# Getting permission from the master of the vessel

Tags: united-kingdom, etiquette

I'm crossing the English channel on a ferry soon and I'd like to do some radio while on it.

According to my license (full British Ofcom amateur radio license), to be able to do this, I need permission from the master of the vessel.

What should this permission look like? I take it should be written.

Comment: Have you asked the shipping company? It seems they would be the one to ask.

Comment: I'm reopening this question as I feel that it reasonable to consider the question of, _in general,_ how should hams request permission in the cases where the permission is legally relevant? Etiquette, explaining things to non-hams, being consistent with established practice so we feel "professional" about our amateur business, etc.

Comment: Also, a good answer should address these things in general and with justification rather than solely "I did this and it worked for me once".

Comment: Please post your findings once you learn them - I'd like to do this myself one day.  (I even have a additional rare VE0 callsign that is only usable on ships plying between international ports, which would be very fun to use.  I think only Canada has such prefixes.)

Answer (score 5):

Written permission or prohibition to bring ham radio gear on board is proffered by some of the large cruise lines. For example, [Carnival](https://help.carnival.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2261/~/carnival-cruise-line-additional-prohibited-items%2C-exemptions-and-other) gives written permission by way of their published policy where as [Norwegian](https://www.ncl.com/prohibited-items) specifically denies permission to possess ham radio equipment on board (or even a satellite phone!).

Once on board, the captain of the ship must be approached to garner permission to operate. You can expect to be asked about the antenna, the frequencies involved, the amount of power, and how the radio will be powered. The captain will view most of this information with an eye toward the safety of fellow passengers and the potential for interference with on-board radio equipment.  If the captain is so inclined he or she will then give verbal permission but most likely with the caveat that at his or her request, you must immediately cease operations. The captain most certainly will not take the time during boarding to grant you any type of written permission - everything will be verbal.

So unless your country's regulations specifically require that you obtain written permission, you should be able to operate with the captain's verbal permission. Do keep in mind that your home country's radio regulations may only be applicable when you are within your country's own territorial waters. If you are in international waters, often the flag of the ship determines the applicable regulations for the ham radio operator.